# Adicionando linhas DataTable

Tags: ajax, json

Eu tenho uma table, que preciso preencher ela dinamicamente, conforme o usuário for adicionando as informações. 
Como posso pegar essas informações, eu já tenho a função que pega, e adicionar no DataTable ?
Segue a função que eu pego os campos preenchidos:

```
 function Adicionar() {
    var url = "/PedidoFornecedor/Adicionar";
    var ProdutoID = $("#produtoid").val();
    var CodigoProduto = $("#idproduto").val();
    var Qtd = $("#qtd").val();
    var PrecoCusto = $("#precocusto").val();
    var DescontoV = $("#descontov").val();
    var DescontoP = $("#descontop").val();
    var ICMS = $("#icms").val();
    var AliquotaICMS = $("#aliquotaicms").html().replace("%", "");
    var IPI = $("#ipi").val();
    var ISS = $("#iss").val();
    var PedidoID = $("#pedidoid").val();
    var DataEntrega = $("#dataentrega").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
            produtoid: ProdutoID, codigoProduto: CodigoProduto, qtd: Qtd, precoCusto: PrecoCusto,
            descontoV: DescontoV, descontoP: DescontoP, icms: ICMS, aliquotaICMS: AliquotaICMS,
            ipi: IPI, iss: ISS, dataEntrega: DataEntrega, pedidoID: PedidoID
        },
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.resultado) {
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Como posso incluir na DataTable ?

Comment: chamar uma função que busca os dados novamente não solucionaria o problema ?

Comment: Carregando o datatable que você fala?

Comment: Isso, chamaria ele novamente, teoricamente a tabela receberia o dado que acabou de ser cadastrado.

Comment: Mas não ta sendo cadastrado no banco, não ainda, eu preciso mandar os dados, e só depois quando o usuário clicar em outro button salvar.

Comment: Ah sim, podes postar a estrutura da datatable?

Comment: @LucasBrogni ai que eu não estou sabendo, pois utilizo .NET CORE, se tiver algum exemplo pra me auxiliar.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82059/discussion-between-lucas-brogni-and-marianac-costa).